# Word paste table from Excel hash marks instead of values

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, office365, copy-paste

I created a table in Excel with 5 columns. The second column is formatted as date (dd.MM.yyyy). When I copy the table to Word all the dates in the second column are replaced with hash marks "######"?!? How can I fix this?

*Windows 10 PRO, Office 365

Comment: You need fit column width.

Answer (score 0):

Cause:
 The column is "too narrow" to allow showing the content, according to Word.

Remedy:
 Move the mouse pointer slowly horizontally over the column border and it will change shape at some point. Keep it at that point and press down the left mouse button, drag to adjust - while holding the button.
NOTE: You might need to adjust columns to the right before the "failing" column can be adjusted.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this is not really a solution. All figures are visible in Excel before copying to Word

Comment: The office package is not perfect you know ;-) - if you find another way to handle it, then you're welcome to add that as an answer here.

Comment: So, it's a bug?

Comment: Well, "bug" might not be the word - I'd reserve it for things that are harder to skip over. In my opinion this is just one of the quirks in the Office package.

Comment: Considering the fact that there is enough space in Word to replace the hash marks with the actual values (without expanding the column widths) and that this was not the case with the 2013 version of Office (on the same table and copy/paste operations) I would definetely call it a bug.

Comment: FYI: I'm using Office Home & Business 2019 now, and the bug still remains!

Comment: As stated above; one of the quirks in Office, probably been there for ages, ... report it to MS as a bug - if the number of reports is great enough, then it might eventually get fixed. And as always: None or low number of reports <=> No fix.